# Jython: Running a Python script within Java -- Set the PYTHONPATH?

Tags: java, python, jython, pythonpath, jython-2.7

I am trying to run a python v3 script within Java using the `org.python.*` library (a.k.a jython)

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
...
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    MapUtils.debugPrint(new PrintStream(baos), "ENV:" , System.getenv());

    // This just shows that JYTHONPATH and PYTHONPATH are in my system env.

    log.debug("System.getenv(): {}", new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    try(PythonInterpreter pyin = new PythonInterpreter()) {
        pyin.execfile(JYTHON_PY.toString()); // <--- fails here due to module missing.
    }

}
```

`JYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH mvn compile test-compile -pl RMBN-Service surefire:test@jython`

`org.python.core.PyException: ImportError: No module named sysrepo`

I currently run the above line to ensure that JYTHONPATH variable is set, but that doesn't work either. (Based on advice from here: https://www.stefaanlippens.net/jython_and_pythonpath/)

However, within my script, I need modules that are located in my $PYTHONPATH system variable, but the PythonInterpreter is not picking up on that PYTHONPATH (nor JYTHONPATH) variable.

My versions:

- JDK 8
- MVN 3.6
- org.python - jython-standalone - 2.7.2

And my relevant system env:

```
DEBUG RmbnJythonSysrepoTest:54 - System.getenv(): ENV: = 
{
    PATH = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/vagrant/.local/bin:/home/vagrant/bin:/home/vagrant/.local/bin:/home/vagrant/bin java.lang.String
    JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk java.lang.String
    MAVEN_HOME = /opt/maven java.lang.String
    LOGNAME = vagrant java.lang.String
    MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS =  compile test-compile -pl RMBN-Service surefire:test@jython java.lang.String
    _ = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java java.lang.String
    **PYTHONPATH = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages java.lang.String**
    SHELL = /bin/bash java.lang.String
    USER = vagrant java.lang.String
    **JYTHONPATH = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages java.lang.String**
    M2_HOME = /opt/maven java.lang.String
    HOME = /home/vagrant java.lang.String
} java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap
```

Comment: If "sysrepo" refers to https://github.com/sysrepo/sysrepo-python (Python bindings for a library written in C), then I would not expect it to work in Jython.

Comment: Well in general, how does one ensure Jython can see the module paths?

Comment: I would expect JYTHONPATH to work. I don't have any other insights besides what it says in the article that you link to.